# how to authenticate to a linux server (from a Windows client)

Tags: windows, linux, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a small client/server application, written in C, that needs to authenticate with a Linux server.

I do not want to transmit a password in clear text across the wire, nor do I want to invent some MD5+nonce system.

I'm hoping to find something 'standard' for this,  what are my options?

I'm hoping that someone can point me to an API set, both on Windows and Linux, that are compatible and intended for interop?

Comment: My first thought is to invoke `plink.exe` and access it through a pipe.  Can't go wrong with SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/), which gives you an API for connecting to SSH servers on linux. It's really easy to use and includes a helpful [tutorial](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutorial.html).